# Updating in an editable gridview once it has been displayed after the updatepanel it is in has been made visible by the user

Tags: vb.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have been searching forums and trying to solve this for a few days now but I'm stuck. Apologies if this is something so simple and obvious that I have missed. Although I have found posts similar to my issue, they are not quite the same.

Here is the outline of what my Web app partly does:

1. shows a simple asp:dropdownlist
2. When the user selects a value, the appropriate updatepanel is made visible (these update panels are visible = false in the Page_Load code behind), showing an editable gridview:

   `Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
       If DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value <> "0" Then
       If DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Activate or Inactivate Users" Then
       UpdatePanel1.Visible = True
   End If
   ...`

   ```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="iMemberId" HeaderText="iMemberId" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="iMemberId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sFname" HeaderText="sFname" SortExpression="sFname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sSname" HeaderText="sSname" SortExpression="sSname" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="dDateCreated" HeaderText="dDateCreated" SortExpression="dDateCreated" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sEmailAddress" HeaderText="sEmailAddress" SortExpression="sEmailAddress" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="sMobileNo" HeaderText="sMobileNo" SortExpression="sMobileNo" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="bActiveMember" HeaderText="bActiveMember" SortExpression="bActiveMember" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" Runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:PTCCHomeTestConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MemberTable] ORDER BY [sSname]" 
            UpdateCommand="UPDATE MemberTable SET sFname = @sFname, sSname = @sSname, sEmailAddress = @sEmailAddress, sMobileNo =, bActiveMember = WHERE (iMemberId = @iMemberId)">
        <UpdateParameters>
                            <asp:Parameter Name="sFname" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="sSname" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="sEmailAddress" />
                            <asp:Parameter Name="iMemberId" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

   </ContentTemplate>
   ```

Each gridview's select and update queries have been tested and work fine. I have tested the gridviews in a page where they are all visible ( and it all works fine, but I would like to have the only the appropriate gridview visible depending on which one the user selects from the dropdown list.

1. The user should then be able to click Edit on a chosen row and update it. The gridview displays fine, properly populated, but when the user clicks on the Edit (to update) link in a row I get the error:

---

"Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page...

Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or  in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.]
   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId, String argument) +144
   System.Web.UI.Control.ValidateEvent(String uniqueID, String eventArgument) +111
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +32
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +9643314
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929"`
```

---

I have tried the following (but still the same error):

I added a Render sub that registers all the values from the select and update for event validation:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

    'override (page) Render and loop over the GridView Rows
    Dim row As GridViewRow
    For Each row In GridView3.Rows
        If (row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then        
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(New System.Web.UI.PostBackOptions(Me.GridView3, "Select$" + row.RowIndex.ToString()))
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(New System.Web.UI.PostBackOptions(Me.GridView3, "Update$" + row.RowIndex.ToString()))          
        End If   
    Next

    MyBase.Render(writer)
```

...

I also tried to rebind the gridview and datasource:

```
    If Not (IsPostBack) Then
       SqlDataSource2.DataBind()
       GridView3.DataBind()
    End If
```

I have also tried to add the EnableEventValidation="false" in the Page tag. What happens is that I now can press the Edit link but then the UpdatePanel disappears (as per the Page_Load) and when I then select the value from the dropdown list it appears again with the row in Edit mode, but with blanks instead of the row's current values.

I also tried defining the datasource of the gridview outside of the same updatePanel that the gridview is in but that did not make any difference.

Just to confirm, if I don't make the UpdatePanels visible=false in the Page_Load code so the user can see all of them then the gridviews work fine with updating rows. This makes me think that the issue lies with the statelessness as if I understand correctly, when an Edit link is pressed the Page_Load code is called again and the dropdownlistvalue is no longer held, thus making the updatepanel which the gridview is in visible=false again.

So, is there any other way to make the updatepanels hidden depending on the dropdownlist selection that is not Page_Load? Could this be where a solution lies?

Or another way to have the dropdownlist chosen value persist after an Edit link (Page_Load call) is done?

I think that I'm sort of on the right track but it would be really helpful to get a little guidance.

Comment: Its a shame there was never any followup on this...